# Code block in View not able to access base View Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've created a Base View in my project to hold the basic properties that can be accessed anywhere in any of the views. The `BaseView` class contains the following properties. `WebSession`, `WebRequest`, `WebMain`, etc.

When I try to access the properties from within the views, they are accessible. But, I had a requirement when I had to set some global variable on the top of the view. So I created those variables in a separate code block on top of the view. Here is the code...

```
@(
    Dim panelInfoVisibility As Boolean = False
    Select Case WebSession.Menu
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Home
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Reservieren
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Kaufen
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Verkaufen
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Member
            If Request.RawUrl.Contains("login") Then
                panelInfoVisibility = True
            End If
    End Select
)
```

This code gives compilation errors when compiled that `'WebSession' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

while in the view below I am using this variable like this...

```
@If panelInfoVisibility Then
    @: <div id="panelInfo">Here it goes....</div>
End If
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue most likely is related to the fact that `FormContext` does not exist in your BaseView layout file when it is being processed.  It is not clear from your question how your BaseView class is derived, but instantiating a FormContext is a good place to start.  Add the following at the top of your BaseView:

```
Me.ViewContext.FormContext = New FormContext()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that has definitely helped removing the earlier compiler error, but now a new error is shown up stating: `Expression Expected` on line 5 which is this line: `@(`. Don't know what have I done wrong in this. My BaseView class is derived from `WebViewPage` (and `WebViewPage(Of TModel)`)